# @import styles in angular component's styles with ::ng-deep

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using Angular 5, angular-cli with scss.

I'm creating angular component that uses 3rd party component ([angular-tree-component](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component)). I need to import styles for the tree. Because of styles isolation in angular (using the default emulated view encapsulation) the only way how to achieve it is using `::ng-deep`, like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    @import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';
}
```

But this does not work - it looks like the `@import` is ignored inside the `:host ::ng-deep`. I workarounded it by copying the content of the css file directly within the brackets but its suboptimal as if the referenced package was upgraded then I would have to manually replace the content with the new styles.

Only other workaround I can think of is changing the view encapsulation to `None` but it seems even worse as it makes the styles global.

Is there any better option?

Comment: including the `.css` extension creates a whole different behaviour: see http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Answer (score 22):

For me, in an Angular CLI 6 project, all works fine when not including the file's suffix. Like if the actual file is `simplemde.min.css`:

```scss
:host ::ng-deep {
    // For proper scoping, do not include the .css file suffix here
    @import '~simplemde/dist/simplemde.min';
}
```

So, the above works without the need for `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. And it also makes non-scoped content (typically HTML that is created at runtime outside of Angular, like in my case the HTML generated for [the SimpleMDE Markdown editor](https://simplemde.com/)) be styled as expected.

Some background:

With the suffix, the `@import` is actually processed as well; whenever my component was instantiated a scoped `<style>` element was added to `<head>`:

[image: with file suffix]

Note that this yields scoping for `_ngcontent`, and this does not work well for `::ng-deep`, leaving dynamic child content unstyled.

However, without the suffix, one gets:

[image: without file suffix]

Above, the scoping is using `_nghost`.

I wonder if this is a bug, or documented behaviour. (And maybe things are even different for Sass files? Using `@import` for CSS [is non-standard behaviour which will be removed in future versions of LibSass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362)...)

Note that `:host` is needed. With just `::ng-deep` the result *with* the file suffix is the same. But *without* the file suffix the styles are not scoped at all when not using `:host`:

[image: without file suffix, without host]

Looking at the rendered web pages I have very much been fooled into thinking this worked too (and one's own styles are still nicely scoped, so this is a partial success). But the third party CSS is effectively imported without any scoping when not using `:host`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/deep/ {
    @import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';
}
```

Comment: While this may _seem_ to work, peek in the HTML to make sure that the styles are still scoped. In my tests, leaving out `:host` from `:host ::ng-deep` resulted in CSS being imported without any scoping at all. (This happened to look okay in my case, but this is just like if one had added the file to the global `styles` in `angular.json` for an Angular CLI 6 project.)